# Excel how to SUMIF with multiple criterias in Range of Column

Tags: excel, formula, sumifs

[image]

Above picture is just a simple Files that I created, My original file is complicated and has a range of numbers in Criteria field.
NOTE: I just want only one Formula to get final Answers, not many Formulas then sum again those lines. (Using EXCEL)

Thanks and appriciate

p/s: Sorry for my rip English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula in the upper right is close. You can use:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(C3:C23,K5:K10,D3:D23))
```

However, this in an array formula, so you must confirm this formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER for it to work properly

And if you don't want to have a range that contains your criteria, you can list it right in the formula like this:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(C3:C23,{20,22,24,25,26,28},D3:D23))
```

(Same thing - must confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

Comment: Sorry, Like I said above, Because my original file has multiple of numbers, hundred of numbers, then cannot write as "20,22,24,..."
And I want this =SUM(SUMIF(C3:C23,K5:K10,D3:D23)) but incorrect...
But with CTRL - SHIFT - ENTER is Awesome correct!!!
But I tried to type exactly (after press Ctrl - Shift - Enter) but it wont work... I must write then press them, it works